# How to change TextFormField input text color in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Doing UI for a flutter app at uni, I just want the text typed into the TextFormField to be white. It seems unnecessarily difficult. I've tried googling etc but can't see an obvious answer.

```
  new Theme(
    // this colors the underline
    data: theme.copyWith(
      primaryColor: Colors.white,
      hintColor: Colors.transparent,

    ),
    child: new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(32.0, 40.0, 32.0, 4.0),
      child: TextFormField(

          key: Key('username'),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          controller: usernameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(

              fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              filled: true,
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(

                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(

                  const Radius.circular(8.0),
                ),
                borderSide: new BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
              labelText: 'Username',
              labelStyle:
                  new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0)),
          style:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: textTheme.button.color),
          validator: validateUserName,
          onSaved: (val) => this.loginFields._username = val),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 157):

This will do:

```dart
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
)
```

Answer (score 16):

For anyone trying to do this from a material app's `theme: ThemeData` property, the color can be changed using the `subtitle1` text theme style.

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  theme: ThemeData(
    ...
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      ...
      subtitle1: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red, // <-- TextFormField input color
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not able to figure this out. But this should not be under subtitle1 in the first place. I think this makes no sense.

Comment: Now `TextFormField` and `TextField` are using `titleMedium` as default textStyle.

Answer (score 11):

You can use **style** inside TextFormField.

#### Example :

```
          TextFormField(
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
```

Answer (score 10):

Puedes usar `style: TextStyle`

```
body: Center(
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
            Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                            TextFormField(
                                controller: field,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red),
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: 15,
                                        top: 8,
                                        right: 15,
                                        bottom: 0
                                    ),
                                    hintText: 'name',
                                ),
                                validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Please enter some text';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                },
                            ),
                        )
                    ]
                )
            )
        ]
    )
)
```

Comment: You put textField inside a textfield

Answer (score 6):

You can use this to change everything

```
TextFormField(
                //controller: _phoneController,
                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black
                ),
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white
                  ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    //contentPadding:
                    //EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 11, top: 11, right: 15),
                    hintText: "New Playlist"),
              ),
```

Answer (score 4):

To use the style **locally**, use:

```
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
)
```

To **globally** set the color (**after 2023** when subtitle text style is deprecated), the only way is to set titleMedium text style.

```
ThemeData(
  ...
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    ...
    titleMedium: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
),
```

If local text style is not set, Flutter uses titleMedium style as a default for the input style.

Answer (score 3):

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: TextFormField(
  cursorColor: Color(0XFFFFCC00)//Cursor color change
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Color(0XFFFFCC00),
    decorationColor: Color(0XFFFFCC00),//Font color change
    backgroundColor: Color(0XFFFFCC00),//TextFormField title background color change
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

**Changing Input textColor using the `ThemeData` :**

### **Material 2**

In Material 2 `TextField` is using `titleMedium`.

```
ThemeData(
  ...
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    ...
    titleMedium: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red, // <-- TextFormField input color
    ),
  ),
),
```

### **Material 3**

In Material 3 `TextField` is using `bodyLarge`.

```
ThemeData(
  ...
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    ...
    bodyLarge: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red, // <-- TextFormField input color
    ),
  ),
),
```

*Follow [this Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118267) for any changes*

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to change the textColor using the ThemeData.

Now TextField is using `titleMedium`.

So,

```
ThemeData(
  ...
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    ...
    titleMedium: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red, // <-- TextFormField input color
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing input text color in this line `TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: textTheme.button.color)`, so in order to set in to `white` just use `Colors.white` constant instead of `textTheme.button.color`.

More about text style [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

Overview: The textFormField style is set to a TextStyle defined as MediumStyle.  The style affects the characters being displayed in the textbox.  Whereas, the labelStyle affect the font displays of the inputdecoration.

```
TextFormField(
            style: MediumStyle,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            focusNode: _employeeEmailFocus,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Employee Email", labelStyle:MediumBoldStyle),
            validator: (val)=> null,
            onSaved:(value)=> this._employeeEmail=value,
            onFieldSubmitted: (term){
                _fieldFocusChange(context,_employeeEmailFocus,_passwordFocus);
            },

            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
),
```

Answer (score -11):

Add a inputdecoration class for textformfield
 this is i think so

```
    decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixStyle: new TextStyle(

              ),
```

Comment: Please remove this answer. It is so wrong. People will just downvote it.