# Is there a way to set a color of a text in the InputDecoration in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In HTML,

```html
<label for="userName" class="label"><span style="color:red;">* </span>User Name</label>
```

It is easy to put red * character in the html tags.

But in the flutter,

```dart
TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    autofocus: false,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'User Name',
        labelText: '<span style="color : red;">*</span> User Name'),
    initialValue: _userProfileDataMap['userName'],
)
```

this is for `TextFormField` with label and only it allows string output

How can I try to do like HTML style?

Comment: [style in TextFormField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52611096/10367725)
here is your answer.

Comment: style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
) is for value, not for a specific label.

Comment: Now label can only set string type, if you can set widget, there should be more custom space

Answer (score 2):

Set a `labelStyle` to change the label text color.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'User Name',
    labelText: 'User Name',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Directly Change it in style.

```
 TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red), //color for input text
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your username',
                        labelText: 'Username',
                      ),
                    ),
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Set a `hintStyle` to change label text color.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Username',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
),
```

There are 2 stages of a label text, when it is on top of input field, it will use `hintStyle` and when it is above input field i.e, vertically above and not on top of it, you need to use `labelStyle` like this:

```
labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
```

So use both of them together:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter your username',
    labelText: 'Username'
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
),
```

Comment: I asked '<span style="color : red;">*</span>' in the flutter. not whole

Comment: @YangJaeLee Different styles for different words can be defined using [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) but I don't know whether it's even possible to use it in `labelText` as `labelText` takes a String and not a Widget. [zefyr](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr) package has been suggested by some people for rich text styling, you may want to look into it to see if it helps.